# Validate SSL Certificate on OpenVAS using Let'sEncrypt

Tags: ssl, certificate

I'm am trying to validate an certificate on OpenVAS. Where can I reference the certificate file (.pem)?

I already create them using Let'sEncrypt (CERTBOT).

Answer (score 0):

On my Kali install pem's go in /var/lib/openvas/CA, private keys go in /var/lib/openvas/private/CA. There are 3 certs configured, cacert, clientcert and server cert. I believe you can swap out servercert (both private and public) and it should pick it up on restart.